# OneLogin OAuth2 grant types

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, onelogin

Reading from the documentation I'm not sure if OneLogin provides support for these OAuth2 grant types:

- Resource Owner Password Credential Grant
- Authorisation Code Grant

Had someone implemented one of these? Are they possible? I need at least ROPCG for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Onelogin is supporting the auth code grant (as part of openID Connect) but you'll have to wait a bit before anything beyond the userinfo endpoint is available as part of this.